# Shift JOLT transformation - facing problem with below transformation

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I'm trying to convert below input json to flatten necessary column names and its values while retaining all metadata.

Below is the **input json** that I've for my CDC use-case.

```
{
  "type": "update",
  "timestamp": 1558346256000,
  "binlog_filename": "mysql-bin-changelog.000889",
  "binlog_position": 635,
  "database": "books",
  "table_name": "publishers",
  "table_id": 111,
  "columns": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "id",
      "column_type": 4,
      "last_value": 2,
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name",
      "column_type": 12,
      "last_value": "Suresh",
      "value": "Suresh123"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "email",
      "column_type": 12,
      "last_value": "Suresh@yahoo.com",
      "value": "Suresh@yahoo.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the expected **output json**

```
[
  {
    "type": "update",
    "timestamp": 1558346256000,
    "binlog_filename": "mysql-bin-changelog.000889",
    "binlog_position": 635,
    "database": "books",
    "table_name": "publishers",
    "table_id": 111,
    "columns": {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Suresh123",
      "email": "Suresh@yahoo.com"
    }
  }
]
```

I tried the below spec from which I'm able to retrieve columns object but not the rest of the metadata.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "columns": {
        "*": {
          "@(value)": "[#1].@(1,name)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Any leads would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got the JOLT spec for above transformation. I'm posting it here incase if anyone stumbles upon the something like this.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "columns": {
        "*": {
          "@(value)": "columns.@(1,name)"
        }
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```